# "ValueError: dictionary" error on setting node attributes from dictionary on NX

Tags: python, dictionary, networkx

I'm trying to add attributes to my nodes from dictionary. My nodes represents Actors from my data, and I'm trying to add the movie genres they played before as an attribute.

```
G.nodes
```

> NodeView(('Stan Laurel', 'Oliver Hardy', 'James Finlayson', 'Forrester Harvey', 'Wilfrid Lucas'.....

```
attribute_dict
```

> {'Leslie Howard': ['Comedy',
> 'Drama',
> 'Romance',
> 'Thriller',
> 'Adventure',
> 'Documentary',
> 'War',
> 'History'],
> 'Wendy Hiller': ['Comedy',
> 'Drama',
> 'History',],
> 'Wilfrid Lawson': ['Comedy',
> 'Drama',
> 'Romance',
> 'War',....]

I'm trying to do:

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G, attribute_dict)
```

But taking that error.

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call > last)
>  in 
> ----> 1 nx.set_node_attributes(G, actor_movie_dict)
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-> packages\networkx\classes\function.py in set_node_attributes(G, values, > name)
> 693         for n, d in values.items():
> 694             try:
> --> 695                 G.nodes[n].update(d)
> 696             except KeyError:
> 697                 pass
>
> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is > required

My length of dictionary is 5583 and I have 15518 nodes. Is that could be the reason or am I missing something?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: better create minimal working code with some example data - so we could simply copy and run it.

Comment: maybe `set_node_attributes` can't use dictionary with lists inside. Maybe it needs single values.

Comment: Updated my error message. Let me do the minimal working code. @furas

Comment: documentation for [set_node_attributes](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes.html) mentions `dict of dict` (not `dict of list`). And examples also shows rather `{node_number: {attribute_name: attribue_value}, ...}` - Maybe you should have `{'Leslie Howard': {'genders': ['Comedy', ...]}, ...}`

Comment: Oh. Thank you for your time. Let me try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation mentions **If values is a dict or a dict of dict**, but I tried dict of list so It did not worked.

So instead of this:

> {'Leslie Howard': ['Comedy', 'Drama'...

I changed it to:

> {'Leslie Howard': {'Movie types': ['Comedy', ...]}, ...}

Now it works. Thank you @furas.